# Set featured image from custom field URL

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I have a custom field which saves the URL of an image that is uploaded. This is achieved by obtaining the medium size like this:

```
$image = get_field('fl_image');
$my_thumb = $image['sizes']['medium'];
```

The output of the custom field is simply the URL of the medium size picture. e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/10/6/duck-300×169.jpg
```

How can I set this as a featured image when a post is saved/updated and the featured image is empty?

Comment: Featured images are stored by saving a post meta field with key `_thumbnail_id` and the value is an attachment ID, so you would need to save your image properly as an attachment for things to work out.  There's an easy way out, possibly, if you control your theme and can edit the code.  You could check for a featured image and if there isn't one, display your image instead.  If that's an acceptable alternative, let me know and I'll knock up some code.

Comment: I just re-read your question.  If your field saves the URL of an image as you state then you wouldn't have any image sizes set like that.  Can you expand your question to explain exactly how you have your field set up?

Comment: This is an ACF image field and I have the option to upload an image and save the output of this field as a URL of the image. At the moment I upload the image, the medium size is automatically created in my uploads folder but not attached to the post, as you are stating.

Comment: Being attached to the post and being an attachment are different things.  What do you get if you add the line `print_r($image)` to your code?

Comment: sorry for being slow.. how can I run print_r($image) and see the output?

Comment: Add it as a third line of code after the two in your question.  The results of the `print_r` will tell me what I need to know to try and give you an answer.

Comment: I created a function and put it in my functions.php with that line but I don't see any output when I refresh the post page. Please see the update on my question for the function I used.

Comment: I do need to see that output - you called the function from within the loop on a template for a post that has one of these images set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46789/discussion-between-joanna-mikalai-and-andy-macaulay-brook).

Answer (score 1):

Hook [`'acf/save_post'`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfsave_post/) after ACF saves the `$_POST['acf']` data. Then check to see if the post [`has_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) and [`set_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) if it doesn't.

```
function save_acf_image_to_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) {

    $image = get_field( 'fl_image' );

    if ( ! empty ( $image ) ) {

        if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {

            $image_id = isset( $image[ 'id' ] ) ? $image[ 'id' ] : ( isset( $image[ 'ID' ] ) ? $image[ 'ID' ] : '' );

            if ( ! empty ( $image_id ) ) {

                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image_id );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'save_acf_image_to_post_thumbnail', 20 );
```

This assumes the `Return Value` is an `Image Object`.

[image]

---

It's also possible to trick `has_post_thumbnail` and `post_thumbnail_html` to render your custom field `Image URL` when the metadata is missing.

Spoof `has_post_thumbnail`:

```
function filter_post_metadata( $value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ) {

    if ( $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id' && ! $value ) {

        return empty ( get_field( 'fl_image' ) ) ? $value : - 1;
    }

    return $value;
}

add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', 'filter_post_metadata', 20, 4 );
```

Doctor `post_thumbnail_html`:

```
function filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_ID, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {

    $image = get_field( 'fl_image' );

    if ( ! empty( $image ) && (empty( $post_thumbnail_id ) || $post_thumbnail_id === -1) ) :

        $html = sprintf( '<img width="%s" height="auto" src="%s" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" >', "100%", esc_url( $image)  );

    endif;

    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_post_thumbnail_html', 20, 5 );
```